# ASP , extract data from bbs

Tags: asp.net, html

HI all.

im new to asp programming.

i want to extract data from bbs,http://sports.williamhill.com/bet/en-gb/betting/y/5/tm/Football.html

my plan is first, if i click some button, i go above page and extract 'Daily Match List'.

and with extracted data, i want to remove some unneed part of html source.

so what i want to extract data will be such like following

```
19:45 UK  swidon VS Bristol Rovers 21/20 23/10 13/5

19:45 UK  Brazil VS Ukraine         4/9  16/5  6/1

.

.

.
```

then i want insert this extracted data to excel file .

sorry my english

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look at using httpwebrequest - you can then make a web request to that page and access the html from the response.  You then need to look for something that will identify the block of information your after and strip this out of the response.

However, there are some downsides to taking a screen scrap approach, if William Hill decide to change the format of the web page then it may break your code.

http://www.netomatix.com/HttpPostData.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx

Cheers Tigger

Comment: sorry Paul, but there isnt an easy way of getting the data unless the company offer some kind of api.  Failing that your left with scraping the data from the site.  Good way of doing that is to use httwebrequest, which will return the html you see on the web page but in a form you can access from your code.  If you havent got the coding skills then look at some of the auction sites out there, its amazing what people will do for a few pounds.